# Configuration in Spring Boot unit test - Failing to load ApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit5

I am trying to test a specific `@Service` but it is failing to load the applications configuration. I am rather new to Spring Boot, so I am just going through the aches and pains. What am I missing?

My service looks like this:

```java
@Service
public class Features extends ArrayList<Feature> {

    @Autowired
    private AppConfig config;

    @PostConstruct
    public void loadFeatures() {
        //...
    }
}
```

My configuration class:

```java
@ConfigurationProperties("sample-feature-app")
public class AppConfig {

    private final String packageFeatures;

    @ConstructorBinding
    public AppConfig(String packageFeatures) {
        //...
    }
}
```

My unit test:

```java
@ContextConfiguration(classes = AppConfig.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Features.class)
public class ServiceFeatureTest {

    @Autowired
    Features features;

    @Test
    public void loadFeatures_CheckSize() {
        System.out.println(features.size());
    }
}
```

When I go to start the test for `loadFeatures_CheckSize()`, I get a Spring initialization error.

```sh
Parameter 0 of constructor in com.example.package.features.ApplicationConfiguration required a bean of type 'java.lang.String' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'java.lang.String' in your configuration.
```

Comment: There is a lot going on in here for this to be a simple unit test. It looks like an integration test setup. Are you trying to unit test the `@Service` or integration test it? Furthermore, what is the `inidicators` object used in `ServiceFeatureTest#loadFeatures_CheckSize`? And is the `AppConfig` just a Spring configuration class? If that's the case, you shouldn't Autowire it, you can annotate the class with `@Configuration` annotation, it will be picked up by Spring Boot component scan, if it is in a subpackage of the `@SpringBootApplication` / `@SpringBootConfiguration` annotated class.

Comment: @Troley The `indicators` was a missed refactor. I updated OP to address it. I am trying to isolate the `Features::loadFeatures()` method to verify whether or not it is loading features successfully. I have a JSON file in my `src/test/resources/features.json` that has a few test features. My configuration in `src/test/resources/application.yaml` specifies the path to the `features.json` file. I am trying pull the path to `features.json`, `packageFeatures`, via my configuration

Comment: Ah I see. By the way, when testing with JUnit in Java, you should use assertions method and not `System.out.println`, so in your case you could use `org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(features.size() > 0)` (assuming you are using JUnit5 judging by the tag). Do you by the way have a Spring bean `packageFeatures` in your application context? Because that is kind of where your problem rises. I reproduced your problem and it works when I create that bean.

Comment: I'll post what I have as answer and we'll see whether it'll help you, or whether it needs more context.

Comment: Sorry it took a while. Posted the answer. Do let me know if something is not clear or if you still run into a problem.

Comment: @Troley Thank you for taking the time to reply. I will review your answer. Also, the class is from a different project that wasn't originally a Spring application. That was more of a placeholder unit test just to see if I can get it to run. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah sure, you're welcome. Ah, that might make it a bit more complicated. Well I hope it'll help and if not then we'll look further into it.

Answer (score 1):

First, we have the configuration class. Here the code is almost equal to yours, but notice the `@Configuration`. This annotation tells Spring that the class should get picked up by automatic component scanning. That is because it contains a meta-annotation `@Component`. The annotation you are using, `@ConfigurationProperties` doesn't get picked up by component scanning, because it is not a `@Component` annotated annotation.

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;

@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    // Other bean configurations...
}
```

Next the `@Service`. As I understood, you're filling the `Features` with data from `features.json` file. The path to this file is saved in `application.yaml` file. I'm assuming the path to `features.json` file is configured under the `sample-feature-app` configuration key. In that case you could simply do this in your service:

```
import com.example.demo.model.Feature;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import java.util.ArrayList;

@Service
public class Features extends ArrayList<Feature> {

    @Value("${sample-feature-app}")
    private String packageFeautres;


    @PostConstruct
    public void loadFeatures() {
        // Load the data from features.json ...
    }
}
```

The configuration will get loaded into the variable `packageFeatures` because of the `@Value` annotation, which injects the configuration specified between the `${}`. In this case it will be the path to the json file. To make it complete, this is my `application.yaml` file under src/main/resources:

```
sample-feature-app: /path/to/features.json
```

And onto the last part, the test. In the test you basically load the 'slice' which is required for the test, which is in this case `Features` class. This is done by the `@SpringBootTest(classes = Features.class)` You then simply autowire this bean. And in the test itself you assert whether the size is greater than 0. That is done, as mentioned in the comment under your question, with the `assertTrue` JUnit method.

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

@SpringBootTest(classes = Features.class)
public class ServiceFeatureTest {

    @Autowired
    private Features features;

    @Test
    public void loadFeatures_checkSize() {
        assertTrue(features.size() > 0);
    }
}
```

You don't need the `@ContextConfiguration` annotation anymore, because the `AppConfig` is a `@Configuration` and is detected automatically (it should be if it is in a subpackage of your `@SpringBootApplication` / `@SpringBootConfiguration` annotated main class).

Comment: So if my configuration only consisted of the `packageFeatures` variable, then there would be no need for a configuration class if I'm specifically specifying the `@Value` annotation, is that right?

Comment: That is correct. Because your configuration property (which you are 'loading' with `@Value`) is configured in the `application.yaml` (or `application.properties`) file which Spring Boot by default looks for in your classpath and magically loads into your application context. You basically don't have to do anything for that to work, just have a SpringBootApplication class and have the application.yaml/properties file in src/main/resources and it all just works.

Comment: So the `@Value` annotation is throwing a `FileNotFoundException`. I've encapsulated it with the `${}`. I have followed your examples to a tee. Is there something else I need to add to indicate `@Value` should be deriving a value from my `application.yaml`?

Comment: Hmm, is your `application.yaml` file located in src/main/resources/? So exactly this: `src/main/resources/application.yaml`?

Comment: Correct. And for my unit tests, I have a copy of that in my `src/test/resources/application.yaml`.

Comment: Hm, could you try to add this annotation `@PropertySource("classpath:application.yaml")` on top of `AppConfig` class? And see whether that helps? By the way, do you use IntelliJ IDE? If so, if the file exists, then it should get highlighted when you ctrl + mouseover the file name (you can also click on the highlighted part to go to the file), if the file gets detected by the IDE (which is most of the times good news) .

Comment: I don't have any of these issues in my integration tests. When I run my `main` class unit test, it is fully capable of pulling all necessary configuration.

Comment: I finished refactoring and published the project on [GitHub](https://github.com/ccarv/stix-pattern-evaluator-examples/tree/develop/spe-example-kafka-feed/src/test/java/design/unstructured/examples/spe/example/kafkafeed). Maybe this will help elaborate on my issue. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206548/discussion-between-user0000001-and-troley).